# Can a React component be used in the unmounted state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-component

I have a React component that creates an event listener, and displays a list of links.  Once the user clicks on a link the componentWillUnmount method is called and a new page displayed.  My component continues to function and handle events after it has been unmounted.  This works as intended as I am keeping track of whether my control is mounted or not and calling functions passed in through props based on the mounted/unmounted state.

Everything seems to be working fine, but I've read in the React docs, "componentWillUnmount() is invoked immediately before a component is unmounted and *destroyed*".  I am also aware that isMounted is an anti-pattern so I am keeping track of whether the control is mounted myself.  Is it just a matter of time before my component is destroyed or is my event listener keeping it from being destroyed?

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution for your problem is using a library like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/).  It will handle your state and actions for you, so you don't have to worry about components in an unmounted state.

That being said, this is actually a known memory leak issue in React.  You can see the issue [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7128).

Answer (score 0):

`componentWillUnmount()` Is designed for handling the cleanup of a component. This includes cleaning up event listeners and timers etc. I believe the correct approach would be to remove the event listener in this function.